# updating database record with click event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, rails-activerecord, ujs

Hi I am attempting to remotely update an element within my database from a click event. 
when the click event is triggered I am getting the following error, though I believe I'm using the correct methods

```
Started PUT "/availabilities/131/edit" for 124.168.74.144 at 2013-02-13 08:02:40 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/availabilities/131/edit"):
```

haml click event

```
.six.columns#named_players


 %h5 Named Players
  %table.twelve
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Change Status
        %th Attending
    %tbody
      - @availabilities.each do |a|
        %tr
          %td= full_name(a.user)
          %td
            %ul.button-group.two-up.even
              %li= button_to 'Accept', edit_availability_path(a), :remote => true, :method => :put, :class => 'button tiny success', :disable_with => 'Add'
              %li= link_to 'Decline', '#', :remote => true, :method => :put, :class => 'button tiny alert'
```

controller

```
def update
    @availability = Availability.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @availability.update_attributes(params[:availability])
        format.html { redirect_to @availability, :notice => 'Availability was successfully updated.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you are clicking to `[PUT] "/availabilities/131/edit"` instead of `[PUT] "/availabilities/131/update"`

Comment: so i need to change my route?

Comment: you have to add the update route (if it does not exist yet) and your button (or link) must call the update controller method

Comment: update is in my controller already as stated above, so id need to change the link?

Comment: try something like `link_to 'Decline', controller: 'controller_name', action: 'update', :remote => true, :method => :put, :class => 'button tiny alert'`

Comment: not sure how its passing which param that needs to be updated